# addpeer(node) in the second node caused the data lost in the first node

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle

I set up a private block-chain over Ethereum with geth.

In node 1, I setup two accounts, deployed a contract with token via truffle, then I transferred some token from one account to another, check the acccounts balances, all looks good, also check the eth.account[0].getBalance, good;

Then I setup another node( node 2) in a different box, using addpeer to connect to node 1, then I began to miner.start() in the node 2.

I checked the node 1, the balance in the two accounts were reset to 0.

How can this happen? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that I have some stealthy data in node 2 and the block-chain in node 2 is longer than one in node 1, so after then mining process began, node 1 sync data with node 2.